# Why there's Traversable and Iterable in root in the hierarchy diagram of the Scala collections API?

Tags: scala

Traversable is the top of the collections hierarchy. Its main method is 'foreach' so it allows to do something for each element of the collection.

An Iterable can create an Iterator, based on which foreach can be implemented. This defines some order of the elements, although that order might change for every Iterator.

The only class that extends from Traversable is Iterable. So why not unify the two classes into one class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you yourself have observed, you can always implement `foreach` in terms of `iterator`. The converse is not true, however: you cannot in general implement `iterator` if you only have `foreach`. The only way to do so is to run `foreach` until it finishes, collecting elements into a separate collection, and return an iterator for this collection. This is inefficient for large collections and completely impossible for infinite ones.

However, the standard library indeed does not contain anything which is `Traversable` but not `Iterable`, and it is actually quite hard to come up with examples. Basically, a thing can be `Traversable` but not `Iterable`, if it is something which allows iteration, but which also requires keeping some iteration state which cannot be feasibly externalized inside an iterator. An example could be some wrapper around [SAX API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) which provides push-based XML parsers. These parsers are callback-driven; you provide a callback to the parser, and it runs automatically until the end of the document being parsed, invoking methods on the callback object corresponding to various kinds of elements of an XML structure. Creating a `Traversable` wrapper for a SAX parser is almost trivial; creating an `Iterable` wrapper is impossible (without collecting the results first, which, as I said above, is quite inefficient). On the other hand, JavaSE also provides [StAX API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html), which is basically iterator-based, so an `Iterable` wrapper for a StAX parser can also be implemented quite easily.

Actually, the authors of Scala also realize that `Traversable` is not that useful. And that's the reason why `Traversable` is absent from the [redesigned collections library](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/ongoing-work-on-standard-collections-redesign/293), which is going to be shipped in Scala 2.13. Even another point of view on why `Traversable` is bad can be found [here](https://alexn.org/blog/2017/01/13/traversable.html).